# How to delete macros from an Open Office document?

Tags: openoffice, macros

How to delete macros from an Open Office document?

Answer (score 1):

Go to

```
Tools > Macros > Macro Organizer > OpenOffice.org Basic
```

On the left there is a list of your documents. Click on the plus sign in front of itto open the modules. You should see the the macros and you should be able to remove them.

If you want to delete modules, go to

```
Tools > Macros > Macro organizer > OpenOffice.org Basic > Organizer button
```

Comment: I tried. I am able to delete them. But If I open the document again then still I can see the deleted Macros. I am saving the document also.

Comment: What kind of document is it?

Comment: It is VBA document.

Comment: Maybe this forums thread helps: http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=81416&highlight=